# Assert element not visible with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.9

I've seen similar questions but no answer seems satisfying.
I want to assert that the cookie prompt disappears after being clicked.
Seems like `is_displayed()` does not work as the locator is still available in the source code:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwxPR.png) - prompt visible
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpcnZ.png) - prompt clicked/not visible for the user

I found below solution but I am not very happy with it. Is there anything cleaner I could do?

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(context.driver, 2).until(
        EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, HomePageLocators.GDPR)))
    not_found = True
except:
    not_found = False

assert not_found
```

Comment: That's one good solution you already have !!

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks! I am new to this and I wasn't sure if this is good enough or if there is a better alternative.